# Remove Google Drive Web Auth token javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have set up Web Authentication for Google Drive API. I used the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/auth/web-client), and I can successfully upload and download files. I cannot, though, find reference in the [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/delete) about how to revoke the Authentication (I want to give my users the option). 
I found this on SO : `gapi.auth.signOut()` but it does not remove auth, nor does it give an error in the console. Is there not a gapi.auth method to remove the token?

Comment: Have you tried setting the token to null? the gapi.auth namespace has a method [setToken](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsettokentoken) where I think your web auth is taken. Once set, hopefully its treated properly.

Comment: @adjuremods Good idea. are you thinking `gapi.auth.setToken({token: null})`

Comment: Well, I think there's no need to have the `{token:null}` I think, just set it as `gapi.auth.setToken(null);` and hopefully that works.

Comment: Hmm, tried it. Seemed to work in part, but when I revisit the page, I was hoping it would ask me to agree to the auth, but it didn't . I suppose I have to remove the scopes as well.

Answer (score 0):

To revoke token, you can make a REST call to :

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke

and includes the token as a parameter:

> curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}

[Google reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

Comment: Thought that too when I saw the reference, but results in `gapi.auth2`  undefined. I think that is for Identity or G+. I am just getting drive access